# Why do we need the asyncio.coroutine decorator?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, coroutine

Why do we need the `asyncio.coroutine` decorator? What functionality does it provide?

For example:

```
# import asyncio
# @asyncio.coroutine
def gen():
    value = yield("Started")
    print(value)

a = gen()
a.send(None)
a.send("Done")
```

Now if I uncomment the first two lines and use the `asyncio.coroutine` decorator, I still get the same output.

I mean this is already a `coroutine` - a function that can be paused and passed in with an argument. Why do I need to decorate it with another `coroutine` i.e `asyncio.coroutine`?

Comment: The `async def` and `await` syntax wasn't available until 3.5 while `asyncio` was formally introduced in 3.4...

Comment: But still what value does the `asyncio.coroutine` decorator add to my code? I can use the `generator` as a `coroutine` without additional code right. [My next question is why do we need the `async def` and `await` as a syntax when it can be achieved without that. But I will not mix that with this question.]

Comment: Now I'm not sure what you're asking... you have a normal generator function there that you're sending data back in to - you've been able to do that before any asyncio at all...

Comment: Ok and that is what a `coroutine` is, it doesn't need `asyncio`. So when we decorate a `coroutine` with `asyncio.coroutine` do we add some value to it? For example `Twisted`s `inlineCallbacks` decorator can be used to trigger and run a coroutine till it ends. Something like it accepts a `generator function`, executes it to get the `generator object` ... Then starts it with `None` etc.

Comment: You can then use them as part of an async event loop and have them wait/sleep/cancel each other etc... If you're familiar with twisted, then think of `asyncio` IO as a base for doing the same thing (without all the ready made reactors and protocols)... Might be worth having a read through a tutorial or basic examples of it and take it from there...

Comment: In your example, you don’t need the decorator. It provides you with nothing. You’d only use it if you’re defining a coroutine that will get passed to an event loop. And even then you’d only want to use the decorator if your code is going to run on 3.4; you can use `async def` starting in 3.5.

Comment: I highly recommend looking at the asyncio source code to try to understand this stuff (in particular `asyncio/coroutines.py`).  It seems like documentation and explanations are more clear after looking at the code (it's like the code is documenation for the explanations...).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's important to understand that [generators](http://anandology.com/python-practice-book/iterators.html#generators) and `asyncio` [coroutines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines) - are different things. Coroutines are implemented using generators, but (theoretically) could been implemented without them. Genarators - are part of implementation regarding to coroutines.

Since `asyncio` coroutines are implemented using generators, you can sometimes use generators as coroutines without errors:

```
import asyncio


def main():
    yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('done')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

**Result:**

```
done
```

---

But it doesn't work with every kind of coroutine:

```
import asyncio


def main():
    # yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('done')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

**Result:**

```
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

---

That's why (besides [few other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47095008/1113207) things) `asyncio.coroutine` decorator uses:

```
import asyncio


@asyncio.coroutine
def main():
    # yield from asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('done')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

**Result:**

```
done
```

---

But as already noted by all it doesn't actually matter today: since Python 3.5 decorator and `yield from` have been replaced with keywords `async def` and `await` that's not only nicer, but helps to split coroutines from their implementation details in a better way.

```
import asyncio


async def main():
    # await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print('done')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little bothered by the line "But it doesn't work with every kind of coroutine."  In the code that follows, it seems like you are implying that `main` is a coroutine...  How?  It's just a regular function.  Also, as far as the "sometimes use generators as coroutines," the implemenation I'm looking at will accept any generator as long as it yields `None` or `yields from` something that is accepted as a coroutine.  It's probably a bit of an implementation detail, but still more enlightening than "sometimes."

Answer (score 2):

I'm super late to this party but I was interested from a historical perspective what this decorator did.

The accepted answer is simply wrong, or really a non-sequitur, and editing it would be an entire re-write so better to leave it and answer separately.

For the OPs example, what `@asyncio.coroutine` did was attach the `CO_ITERABLE_COROUTINE` flag to the object's `co_flags`. This allowed the generator to be used with the `await` keyword and also to `yield from` "pure" coroutines that were not themselves generator-derived.

```py
# Check if 'func' is a generator function.
# (0x20 == CO_GENERATOR)
if co_flags & 0x20:
  # TODO: Implement this in C.
  co = func.__code__
  func.__code__ = CodeType(
    co.co_argcount, co.co_posonlyargcount, co.co_kwonlyargcount, co.co_nlocals,
    co.co_stacksize,
    co.co_flags | 0x100,  # 0x100 == CO_ITERABLE_COROUTINE
    co.co_code,
    co.co_consts, co.co_names, co.co_varnames, co.co_filename,
    co.co_name, co.co_firstlineno, co.co_lnotab, co.co_freevars,
    co.co_cellvars)
  return func
```

The decorator had some other uses, notably (as illustrated in the accepted answer), it would transform a regular function into a coroutine if it was not already a generator.